# Concatenando os elementos de uma array

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho no Javascript uma array:

```
var array_soma = [
                   "parte 1",
                   "parte 2",
                   "parte 3",
                   "parte 4",
                 ];
```

Gostaria de ir concatenando cada elemento para a array ficar assim:

```
var array_soma = [
                   "parte 1",
                   "parte 1 parte 2",
                   "parte 1 parte 2 parte 3",
                   "parte 1 parte 2 parte 3 parte 4",
                 ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É simples, você precisa guardar a primeira posição e montar na segunda o que tem na anterior assim por diante.

Utilizando um `for` começando do 1 em diante, exemplo:

```js
var array_soma = [
  "parte 1",
  "parte 2",
  "parte 3",
  "parte 4",
];

var aux = array_soma[0];
for(i = 1; i < array_soma.length; i++)
{
  array_soma[i] = aux + ' ' + array_soma[i]
  aux = array_soma[i];
}

console.log(array_soma);
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma interessante de resolver o problema é construir um novo array resultado com a transformação que pretende. Esse pode ser feito à custa de [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), que lhe simplifica o problema. Pode fazer `push` de cada elemento do original e ir concatenando com o ultimo elemento da nova lista, caso já tenha algum.

Exemplo:

```js
var array_soma = [
   "parte 1",
   "parte 2",
   "parte 3",
   "parte 4",
];

const res = [];
array_soma.forEach((el,idx) => res.push(idx === 0 ? el : res[res.length - 1] + " " + el));

console.log(res);
```

O `res[res.length - 1] + " " + el` faz a concatenação entre `el`(elemento corrente) e o ultimo que já está na lista, o `res[res.length - 1]`.